# TimeZone of a date field is getting set incorrectly upon retrieval from the db

Tags: java, datetime

We have a use case where we read a date from the DB, convert it into UTC, and then use it. Now the date that gets inserted is in the local org time zone of the FC, but when I read it the date remains the same, and its timezone is obtained as UTC. As a result of which, I am not able to convert it into UTC, since the convertor finds that it already is in that timezone.

Any hints on how to tackle this issue?

Comment: can you provide some code example of how you are retrieving it?

Comment: i am using hibernate for doing that

Comment: Keep in mind that java.util.Date does not have a time zone. It simply stores the number of milliseconds since the Epoch (January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT). You only get a timezone when you format the date.